# Are pointer types the only way to "prevent" constructor being called in declaration?

Tags: c++, pointers

I've tried to search for this, but I haven't found any answers. Let's look at this:

```
class Foo
{
    Foo();
    Bar a; // 'a', the object, gets created (even if I don't want to!)
    Bar* b; // 'b', the pointer, gets created, but the object doesn't
}

Foo::Foo()
{
    a = a(); // I'd like to create 'a' here instead. This just "replaces" it
    b = new Bar(); // 'b', the object, gets created
}
```

My question is: can I declare an object without creating it as well? Or do I always have to use pointers?

Comment: Why would you want to? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is: can I declare an object without creating it as well?

No.

> Or do I always have to use pointers?

No.  Pointers are one option.  There are others, such as `boost::optional` (`std::optional` is also in the process of standardization).  There are also smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`).  A standardly available, pre-c++11 option which is easier to manage than a raw pointer would be a `std::vector` where you only ever add one element.

But are you absolutely sure you need this?

Comment: I don't really need it for anything, as I've been using pointer types in scenarios where I need an object to have member variables that must be for example created in a certain order. I was just wondering this. Coming from the world of Java and C#, it feels counter-intuitive that declaring an object also initializes it. Thanks for your answer.